# How can I open my Android App when user click on a specific link (or website redirect to that link) in Android 12 and above?

Tags: android, url, intentfilter, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I want to open my Android app (specific activity) when user clicks on a link or a website redirect to that link. *ex link:  com.abc.efg/callback?wjiofjjfie...*
I have used this primitive way by adding intent filter to that particular activity but it does not work.
everything opens in browser.

```
<activity
            android:name=".UrlActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:host="com.abc.efg"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:host="com.abc.efg"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

i have also searched a lot and found on android documentation that from android 12 and later **we have to make this url an App Link
**
refer- [text](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links)
so, is their another way to open the app when link clicked without making the link App link?
If not, than how can I make this link an App link?

Comment: From Android 12 your app needs to verify domain. There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079961/how-to-verify-android-app-links-on-android-12-and-higher)

Comment: actually, the problem is the redirection is coming from authentication server and also the redirect has token id and access token that i need to pass in my app and in dynamic link it is not possible to add the parameter in the redirect link in the firebase dynamic link format

Answer (score 0):

From high version Android you can use Firebase dynamic link  , but this will be deprecated soon maybe next 12 months, because I heard Google noticed that